# Base partial design order

Tags: sxa

We have two base partial design. First partial design used to set the logo and navigation and the second partial design have log + navigation + breadcrumb, so we use the base partial design feature in SXA to apply this functionality. However, we notice when the page is rendered, the HTML output looks like below (the logo and navigation get render after the breadcrumb)

Is there a way to re-order the markup?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details regarding how you have created the base partial design and what placeholders you used?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have two partial designs, SXA works on how the Page Design is rendered. So in Page Design, you can add 2 base partial designs.

The first Partial design has logo and navigation
The second partial design has only breadcrumb

and make sure the order is correct in the page design selection.